# Would a url shortened link redirecting to a hidden service be considered part of the dark web?

Tags: onion-services, darknet, url

https://tinyurl.com/ allows you to shorten URLs. Suppose I shorten the hidden service for DuckDuckGo (https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/) to make it: https://tinyurl.com/2lxqxljq. This link redirects to a hidden service meaning you can only view the hidden service through the Tor network. But the tinyurl isn't a hidden service, it only redirects to a hidden service (there is a Captcha Tor users have to fill out). Does this make this specific URL, "https://tinyurl.com/2lxqxljq" part of the deep web, dark web, or what?

Comment: give an example of a clearnet domain forwarding to an .onion domain

Comment: I just did: https://tinyurl.com/2lxqxljq redirects to DuckDuckGo's onion service.

Comment: if Tor can browse the clearnet, and does onion routing while doing so, its small transition from a clearnet site to a hidden service will also be onion routed in my opinion. there's no reason to think Tor will behave differently towards the two, whether they're linked or not

Comment: Yes, but is https://tinyurl.com/2lxqxljq part of the deep web, dark web, or what is my question.

Comment: no. only .onion sites are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.com` sites are not part of the darknet. Only `.onion` sites are.

a `.com` that redirects/forwards to wherever it forwards doesn't change the fact that it is a clearnet `.com`. you might not think there is content for the tinyurl, but there is DNS resolve going on in the background since the `.com` TLD runs on DNS to carry out any operation, including the protocol to forward elsewhere.

If Tor is not used on the tinyurl, it doesn't matter if the `.com` can't reach its forwarded destination. you still put miles into traveling the `.com` as explained in my previous comment regarding DNS resolve, and are just stopped when you get to the border leading to darknetland. Without Tor, there technically was no darknet site accessed whatsoever by going to the tinyurl. only a failed attempt at entry, which was only the second leg of the journey

Comment: The thing is tinyurl.com/2lxqxljq is not like a normal website. There is no content on it. It's basically just https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/ but renamed to have a different URL. It redirects to https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/.

Comment: Also, a darknet is an overlay network for the internet. Do you mean the dark web?

Comment: a .com that redirects/forwards to wherever it forwards doesn't change the fact that it is a clearnet .com. you might not think there is content for the tinyurl, but there is DNS resolve going on in the background. .com runs  on DNS to carry out any operation, including the protocol to forward elsewhere

Comment: But if this tinyurl is a .com, you still can't reach the destination website without using the Tor network. So why isn't this website "technically" a dark web site since the dark web can only be accessed with the tor network?

Comment: it doesn't matter if the .com can't reach its forwarded destination. you still put miles into traveling the .com as explained in my previous comment regarding DNS resolve, and are just stopped when you get to the border leading to darknetland. Without Tor, there technically was no darknet site accessed whatsoever by going to the tinyurl. only a failed attempt at entry, which was only the second leg of the journey

Comment: Okay, I'm going to mark your answer correct, but before that, I need to edit something.